# Failure in Apache+Windows basic authentication

Tags: windows, apache, basic-authentication

.htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile path/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
test:FUgb1Qdh6571o
#This tool is used to generate password file http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/
```

When Apache is running on Windows 10 and I'm trying to access folder authentication dialog appears, however it does not authenticate and does not allow to access restricted folder.

Apache error logs:

```
AH01617: user test: authentication failure for "/folder": Password Mismatch
```

Same setup works correctly when Apache is working on Ubuntu

What could be wrong? Different method of password storing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about online tool you used, but I recommend to use
`htpasswd` tool generate passwords.

Appear that `test:FUgb1Qdh6571o` is generated with algorithm that are not recommended. More info about htpassword could be found at [htpasswd docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

To create a new `db` use:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd test
```

To update password use:

```
htpasswd .htpasswd test
```

PS. I don't recommend to use online passwords generator.
Could be harvested and later used against you.

PS.2 Probably `htpasswd` command is in `apache installation directory`

Answer (score 0):

It could be fault of the line ending encoding, which is `LF` on Linux and `CR LF` on Windows.

In a hex editor `LF` would show up as `0a` whereas `CR LF` would be `0d 0a`. On Ubuntu you can check with `xxd .htpasswd` from the terminal and on Windows you can use Notepad++ to show special characters.

Comment: tried both EOL using notepad++, did not make any difference